# Paypal IPN Donations

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I have a wordpress 1 page site that has an option to download a music track after a paypal donation - with a minimum amount of $3.99.

the button works fine and the paypal payment goes through - but I'm only getting INVALID back from paypal - it doesnt seem to be writing back the content to paypal correctly.

Also - How can I see what paypal is posting back to me?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**inside the included php file:**

```
<?php echo "<p class='small-donate'>Minimum ammount for donation is $3.99</p>
<form method='POST' action=''  target='_top'>
$<input type='text' name='donate_amount' value='0' size='4' class='donate-input'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Donate' class='donate-submit'></form>";
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
// Form has been submitted
  if($_POST['donate_amount'] >= 3.99) {
// Redirect to PayPal
$myurl = site_url();
$fileurl = site_url('wp-content/themes/MY_THEME/content-download-file.php');
header('Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&item_name=Donation for music track&amount='.$_POST['donate_amount'].'&currency_code=USD&business=MY_SANDBOX_TEST_EMAIL&cbt=Download the file&return='.$fileurl.'&cancel_return='.$myurl);
}
else {
echo '<span class="error">Donation must be at least $3.99</span>';
}
}
?>
```

**inside content-download-file.php**

(I got this from paypal developers)

```
<?php
// STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));


// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    //error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
         echo '<section id="download">
<h2>Download song</h2>
 <a href="FILE_PATH">FILE Here</a>
</section>';

    }

 else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you passing any special characters that aren't URL encoded? Can you provide a transaction ID I can look up?

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick what do you mean? im still looking for a way to echo out paypals response.

Comment: If you're passing a character like & * ^ % or similar ones like that without URL encoding them in the response back to PayPal you'll get an invalid response back.
Let me grab one of the test IPN scripts I have that send an e-mail. It writes out the full response and generates an e-mail to whatever location you define and gives you the verification response. You can use that to test with. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script I mentioned:

```
<?php
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate

$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use: 
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
//$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // If testing on Sandbox use:
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
// check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
// process payment

$mail_From = "From: address-here";
$mail_To = "address-here";
$mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
$mail_Body = $req;

//error_log($res, 1, "address-here");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
$emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $emailtext . "\n\n" . $mail_Body, $mail_From);


}
else if (strcmp (trim($res), "INVALID") == 0) {


$mail_From = "From: address-here";
$mail_To = "address-here";
$mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
$mail_Body = $req;

//error_log($res, 1, "address-here");

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
$emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
}

mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $emailtext . "\n\n" . $mail_Body, $mail_From);

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
?>
```

In the "address-here" sections are where you'll need to add in the appropriate e-mail address. This posts everything back to PayPal and it just returned a "VERIFIED" response back.

It's all set for the Sandbox now.

Comment: Im getting this in the email: **Subject:** INVALID IPN and **Body:** My_EMAIL_ADDRESS cmd=_notify-validate

Comment: What is the transaction ID?

Comment: nothing else comes through. Just cmd=_notify-validate -- thats the whole email body.

Comment: could it be because im directing users to paypal via a url string as opposed to an input?

Comment: this is the url the user gets directed to once paid.
http://MY_SITE/wp-content/MY_THEME/keravelt/content-download-file.php?merchant_return_link=Download+the+file&auth=ARd0W4cl42.V5REFVsdC-9AmDKYBOnSL5Y2QcxIKwkmnDXuHIP-WRQt7trMoZyh7YRM9JsL0fLSZY7kSOwmOUpw

Comment: It doesn't matter how the transaction is processed. An IPN post is generated and sent out. There are variables that define the type of transaction but the Donation process, through a form or URL, is always the same. 
IPN doesn't have anything to do with the "return_url" so it doesn't matter if the URL is valid or if buyers actually go back there. 
I just noticed you're not passing a "notify_url" in your button code. That's how you define the IPN page. 
Are you redirecting buyers to the IPN page?

Comment: Yes im redirecting to the IPN page in the `return` part of the url.
so I just changed it to live paypal (not sandbox) and I received 2 emails. 1 saying invalid and 1 worked!

Comment: Redirecting to the IPN page is a problem. It isn't how the process works. IPN is called silently without buyers interacting with the page at all. The information you're receiving is the normal stuff returned during the redirect process to the "return_url" and not the IPN page. 
The IPN post is sent to your notification URL after a payment completes. It does not rely on buyers returning to your site at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31773/discussion-between-mark-and-paypal-patrick)